# Inserting an Action button from an AbstractPropertySection

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a tabbed propertiesContributor (and a few propertySections to go with it) using the **org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertySections** extension point

I should like to place a tab-specific 'refresh' action-button into the action-bar, and cannot see how it should be done. There is a very tantalising method ..

```
TabbedPropertySheetPage.setActionBars( ... )
```

... available in 'createControls()' but I cannot see how I make use of that.

Can anyone point me at some working example code on how to achieve this?

Your clues & boos are most welcome.

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use an instance of org.eclipse.ui.SubActionBars and add the tab-specific Actions to it, like this ...

```
@Override
public void createControls(Composite parent, final TabbedPropertySheetPage aTabbedPropertySheetPage)
{
    ...

    makeActions();
    subActionBars = new SubActionBars( tabbedPropertySheetPage.getSite().getActionBars() );
    subActionBars.getToolBarManager().add( refreshAction );
    subActionBars.getMenuManager().add( refreshAction );
}
```

.. then override aboutToBeShown() and aboutToBeHidden() like this ...

```
@Override
public void aboutToBeShown()
{
    super.aboutToBeShown();
    subActionBars.activate();
    subActionBars.updateActionBars();
}

@Override
public void aboutToBeHidden()
{
    super.aboutToBeHidden();
    subActionBars.deactivate();
    subActionBars.updateActionBars();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way to add a Tab specific action to the view's action bar. You may have to add the action in a section of that tab only.